# Actualizar vista usando patrón observador cada intervalo de tiempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

He creado un **patrón observador** que tiene por finalidad simular una estación del clima y dispositivos que se actualizan con la información, la información de la temperatura, presión y viento se generan **randómicamente**.
Dentro del Controlador, he creado un timer que se ejecuta cada 5 segundos llamando al método Notify de la estación, a fin que la información de la estación del clima sea actualizada.

**Lo que no logro conseguir** es que esa información sea actualizada en la vista, no sé como hacerlo. Qué debo utilizar, si hay algún ejemplo que me pueda ayudar.

Se tiene las siguientes clases:

- IObserverSubject
- IObserverObserver
- IDisplay
- ObserverConcreteObservable
- ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay
- ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay
- Modelo y ViewModel
- ObserverModel
- ObserverModelViewModel

Quedando su diagrama UML de la siguiente forma:

[image: UML observer Pattron]

El código fuente de cada clase / interfase es el siguiente:

**IDisplay**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public interface IDisplay
    {
        public ObserverModel Display();
    }
}
```

**IObserverSubject**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public interface IObserverSubject
    {
        public void Add(IObserverObserver ob);
        public void Remove(IObserverObserver ob);
        public void Notify();
    }
}
```

**IObserverObserver**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public interface IObserverObserver
    {
        public void Update();
    }
}
```

**ObserverConcreteObservable**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public class ObserverConcreteObservable : IObserverSubject
    {
        private readonly List<IObserverObserver> observers = new List<IObserverObserver>();
        private  int param_temp = 0;
        private  int param_presure = 0;
        private  int param_wind = 0;
        private readonly Random _random = new Random();
        public void Add(IObserverObserver observer)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }

        public void Notify()
        {
            foreach(IObserverObserver observer in observers)
            {
                observer.Update();
            }
        }

        public void Remove(IObserverObserver observer)
        {
            observers.Remove(observer);
        }

        public int GetTemperatureState()
        {
            this.param_temp = _random.Next(-90, 90);
            return this.param_temp;
        }

        public int GetPresureState()
        {
            this.param_presure = _random.Next(0, 1500);
            return this.param_presure;
        }

        public int GetWindState()
        {
            this.param_wind = _random.Next(0, 600);
            return this.param_wind;
        }
    }
}
```

**ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public class ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay : IObserverObserver, IDisplay
    {
        ObserverConcreteObservable observerSubject;
        ObserverModel observerModel = new ObserverModel();
        public ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay(ObserverConcreteObservable observerSubject)
        {
            this.observerSubject = observerSubject;
        }
        public ObserverModel Display()
        {
            return this.observerModel;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            observerModel.Temperature= this.observerSubject.GetTemperatureState();
            observerModel.Presure= this.observerSubject.GetPresureState();
            observerModel.Wind =this.observerSubject.GetWindState();
            observerModel.Name = "Phone Display";
        }
    }
}
```

**ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public class ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay : IObserverObserver, IDisplay
    {
        ObserverConcreteObservable observerSubject;
        ObserverModel observerModel = new ObserverModel();
        public ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay(ObserverConcreteObservable observerSubject)
        {
            this.observerSubject = observerSubject;
        }
        public ObserverModel Display()
        {
            return this.observerModel;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            observerModel.Temperature = this.observerSubject.GetTemperatureState();
            observerModel.Presure = this.observerSubject.GetPresureState();
            observerModel.Wind = this.observerSubject.GetWindState();
            observerModel.Name = "Window Display";
        }
    }
}
```

**ObserverModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public class ObserverModel
    {
        public int Temperature { get; set; }
        public int Presure { get; set; }
        public int Wind { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**ObserverModelViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
{
    public class ObserverModelViewModel
    {
        public ObserverModelViewModel()
        {
            ObserverDisplays = new List<ObserverModel>();
        }
        public List<ObserverModel> ObserverDisplays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

El controlador: **ObserverController**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.ObserPattern.ObserverLocation;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.ObserPattern.ObserverReactive_Extensions;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.StrategyPattern.Strategy;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.StrategyPattern.StrategyLog;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.StrategyPattern.StrategyOperation;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.StrategyPattern.StrategySort;
using static WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.ObserPattern.ObserverLocation.ParaLocation;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Controllers
{
    public class ObserverController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult ObserPattern()
        {
            ObserverConcreteObservable weatherStation = new ObserverConcreteObservable();
            ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay phoneDisplay = new ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay(weatherStation);
            ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay windowDisplay = new ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay(weatherStation);

            weatherStation.Add(phoneDisplay);
            weatherStation.Add(windowDisplay);

            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds); // se ejecutara cada x segundos
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => {
                weatherStation.Notify();
            };
            timer.Start(); // indicamos que unicie
            //Console.ReadKey();

            

            ObserverModelViewModel observerModelViewModel = new ObserverModelViewModel();

            observerModelViewModel.ObserverDisplays.Add(phoneDisplay.Display());
            observerModelViewModel.ObserverDisplays.Add(windowDisplay.Display());

            return View(observerModelViewModel);

        }
    }
}
```

La vista: **ObserPattern**

```
@using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
@model ObserverModelViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ObserPattern";
}

<h1>ObserPattern</h1>

@foreach (var element in Model.ObserverDisplays)
{
    <h2> @element.Name</h2>
    <h2>Temperature: @element.Temperature</h2>
    <h2>Presure: @element.Presure</h2>
    <h2>Wind: @element.Wind</h2>
    <br />
}
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "" })">Retornar1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Brother... No copies todo tu proyecto, solo donde tienes problemas o necesitar ayuda

Comment: El principal problema que tienes  es no entender como funciona .NET MVC. La vista se procesa en el servidor y se entrega al cliente, a partir de ahí la vista vive en el navegador totalmente desconectada del servidor que es donde se ejecuta el proceso del observador.

Comment: @Lobos, todo eso lo sé, el Observable no va al navegador, al navegador solo va el resultado de la primera lectura de clima, luego esta lectura se actualiza, como es patrón observador, el observable necesita avisar al observado para de esta forma indicarle que se actualice, cómo esto se hace?

Comment: Lo más cercano que veo para mantenerlo en tiempo real y usando ese patrón sería conectar la vista al servidor con un Web Socket. No te puedo decir como hacerlo porque es muy extenso de explicar y no es el objetivo aquí.

Comment: Tal vez te sea de utilidad investigar sobre signalR

Comment: @Cmbuffa estaba empezando a verlo, vi un ejemplo q lo usaba para chat, pero en caso de chat, la interacción es entre dos clientes (browser), pero no sé si aplique para este caso ya que el Observable estaría a nivel de server y observer a nivel de cliente. Tú q opinas?

Comment: Aqui donde trabajo usamos para actualizar contadores en el frontend o para notificaciones, creo que podria servirte

Comment: @Cmbuffa voy a investigar a ver si encuentro un ejemplo de uso de SignalR con contadores extraídos desde base de datos me parece un buen caso de uso q podría extrapolar a lo que yo requiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando **signalR** pude conseguir lo preguntado. Dejo acá lo realizado por alguien a quien podría servir la solución.
1.- Instalar en el proyecto SignalR
2.- Registrar SignalR en el **Startup.cs** método **ConfigureServices**, agregar la siguiente línea.

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

3.- Crear la ruta por la que SignalR mantendrá la comunicación cliente - servidor para ello en el **Startup.cs** método **Configure**, agregar la siguiente línea.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    endpoints.MapHub<ObserverHub>("/observerhub");
  )
});
```

4.- Agregar una clase que herede de la clase de SignalR **Hub**.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.ObserPattern.Observer
{
    public class ObserverHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Enviar(ObserverModelViewModel observerModelViewModel)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Receive", observerModelViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

5.- Modificar el controlar El controlador: **ObserverController**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ObserPattern()
{
    ObserverConcreteObservable weatherStation = new ObserverConcreteObservable();
    ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay phoneDisplay = new ObserverConcreteObserver_PhoneDisplay(weatherStation);
    ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay windowDisplay = new ObserverConcreteObserver_WindowDisplay(weatherStation);
    weatherStation.Add(phoneDisplay);
    weatherStation.Add(windowDisplay);
    ObserverModelViewModel observerModelViewModel = new ObserverModelViewModel();
    weatherStation.Notify();
    observerModelViewModel.ObserverDisplays.Add(phoneDisplay.Display());
    observerModelViewModel.ObserverDisplays.Add(windowDisplay.Display());
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds); // se ejecutara cada x segundos
    timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        ObserverModelViewModel observerModelViewModelSignarR = new ObserverModelViewModel();
        weatherStation.Notify();
        observerModelViewModelSignarR.ObserverDisplays.Add(phoneDisplay.Display());
        observerModelViewModelSignarR.ObserverDisplays.Add(windowDisplay.Display());
        observerModelViewModelSignarR.Hour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Receive", observerModelViewModelSignarR);
    };
    timer.Start(); // indicamos que unicie
    return View(observerModelViewModel);
}
```

6.- En la vista colocar el siguiente código.

```
@using WebApplication1.Areas.DesignPatterns.Models.Observer.ObserPattern
@model ObserverModelViewModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "ObserPattern";
}
<h1>ObserPattern</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Lectura base</h2>
        @foreach (var element in Model.ObserverDisplays)
        {
            <h4> @element.Name</h4>
            <h4>Temperature: @element.Temperature</h4>
            <h4>Presure: @element.Presure</h4>
            <h4>Wind: @element.Wind</h4>
            <br />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="divWeathers" style="background-color:aqua;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/observerhub")
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();

        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("Conexión exitosa");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err);
        });

        //Funcionalidad para que haga algo cada que HUB reciba información.
        connection.on("Receive", function (observerModelViewModel) {
            let divWeather = document.createElement("div");
            let divDestino = document.getElementById("divWeathers")
            if (1 == 1) {
                let contenido = observerModelViewModel.hour;
                divWeather.textContent = contenido;
                divDestino.appendChild(divWeather);

                for (let element of observerModelViewModel.observerDisplays) {
                    contenido = contenido + "Nombre: " + element.name + "  ";
                    contenido = contenido + " Temperature " + element.temperature + "  ";
                    contenido = contenido + " Presure " + element.presure + "  ";
                    contenido = contenido + " Wind " + element.wind + "  ";
                    contenido = contenido + " </br> "
                }
                divWeather.textContent = contenido;
                divDestino.appendChild(divWeather);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```